# Tensorflow summary event issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have an issue with the tensorflow summary.
When i open it within tensorboard, i can see all the graphs, loss, Average precision and all others scalars data.

As you can see here:
[Tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrUay.png)

But when i try to extract it to export it into csv, i have nothing.

I run this code:

```
from tensorboard.backend.event_processing.event_accumulator import EventAccumulator
event_acc = EventAccumulator(r'path2tfeventfolder')
event_acc.Reload()
# Show all tags in the log file
print(event_acc.Tags())
```

The print is:

*{'images': [], 'audio': [], 'histograms': [], 'scalars': [], 'distributions': [], 'tensors': ['eval_side_by_side_0_0', 'eval_side_by_side_1_0', 'eval_side_by_side_2_0', 'eval_side_by_side_3_0', 'eval_side_by_side_4_0', 'eval_side_by_side_5_0' 'PascalBoxes_Precision/mAP@0.5IOU', 'PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/1', 'PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/2', 'PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/3', 'PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/4', 'PascalBoxes_PerformanceByCategory/AP@0.5IOU/5',
'Loss/RPNLoss/localization_loss', 'Loss/RPNLoss/objectness_loss', 'Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/localization_loss', 'Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/classification_loss', 'Loss/regularization_loss', 'Loss/total_loss'], 'graph': False, 'meta_graph': False, 'run_metadata': []}*

**My final goal is to be able to extract the AveragePrecision for each class (6 differents)**

Comment: You know that you're supposed to replace `path2tfeventfolder` with your own directory where you store logs?

Comment: Btw I don't see any graphs on your screenshot you gave, there's no data aswell

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov
For "path2tfeventfolder" i know, i just changed it for the post.
For the image, here is another one where you can see that there is data: https://ibb.co/jzB51LX

Comment: So what's in `event_acc.Tensors('PascalBoxes_Precision/mAP@0.5IOU')`?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Well i have: 

`TensorEvent(wall_time=1622874848.617934, step=15000, tensor_proto=dtype: DT_FLOAT
 tensor_shape {
 }
 tensor_content: "\344\301\027?"
 )`
So it seems that my data is in Tensors and not in scalars. Now, i just need to find my value which is: 0.5833.

Comment: So i have wall_time, step, but not value, which is the most important for me.

Comment: It's seems it's in `tensor_content`, just in some raw binary format, not sure how to convert though

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Yes, and i succeeded in converting it. Thank you a lot for your help :) ! Have a good day !